# Query the TSX for companies with the 10 greatest percentage losses in the last 30 days?

Tags: stocks

I'm new to investing.

I would like to somehow query TSX companies using the following criteria:

1. 10 greatest losses by percentage
2. Time period: approximately the last 30 days

Is there a way to perform this sort of query on the TSX?

---

*Please feel free to correct my terminology and logic, as I am a complete beginner.*

Comment: Do a Google search on "Worst stocks screener" and you'll find web sites that provide lists.  Many only offer a 1 day ROC (rate of change).  Barcharts offers a 5 day change.  Here's one that offers 1/3/6 month and 1/3/5 year filters.  Im a Yank so it's for US stocks.  Perhaps you can find similar for the TSX: [Screener](https://www.finscreener.com/screener/top-losers?&o=11)